# How to do Multiple Vlookups Across Workbooks Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I need to do a vlookup over thirty files that have the same form ABCD_XXX where only XXX changes across files.

I tried with the function indirect, but it only works when the workbooks were open.

I don't know how to use vba well and the exemples I have seen are only for two different workbooks. I don't want to recode it manually for the thirty workbooks I have.

Could someone help me with this? I have looked thoroughly through the answers already provided and not found one that fits. I would be happy to do it with a formula if possible.

Comment: Indirect will only work with the workbooks open. Is it possible to have one file with 30 summary sheets that link to those 30 workbooks?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure what you mean by this, because I would have to fil by hand by hand these thirty summary sheets or could I do it automatically?

Comment: Import to a database and then do what you need to do. Get in the habit of using a database to store data. Excel is not a database. You could automate all of it with an Access Database.

Comment: It is possible to automate the import of all files in a directory. Your problem solves itself when you use the correct tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other have already alluded to, this really should be done in an actual database.  Access is a good option.  SQL Server is probably overkill, but it would certainly handle the job.  There is MySQL, and a bunch of others as well.  In the meantime, if you want to import everything from 30-something Excel files, into one MasterFile, and point your Vlookup there, that would be a valid temporary solution.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

See the link below for all details.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that is indeed what I have turned to do but it takes a while to run.

Comment: Please mare my answer as useful if it did indeed help you solve your problem.